# "It's a good car, that" - "That" and "this" at the end of sentences

Tags: british-english

I was watching an episode of Top Gear in which they talked about Chinese cars and one of the hosts (Jeremy) said the following:

> It's a good car, that.

I've also heard this sentence somewhere.

> It's a fu***** scam, this is.

I can sort of guess that, *that* in the first sentence is referencing the car, but why say it again? Is it for emphasis?

Could anyone explain how this works?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Adding 'this' and 'that' at the end of a phrase is a part of certain British dialects, particularly Northern England. I am not certain if it is confined to Yorkshire.

Comment: That would explain why i've only heard it in British TV Shows and videos/movies. Thank you very much!

Comment: Apologies. I misread your rep. I see you are a seasoned user :)

Comment: Don't mention it. :)

Comment: The first sentence is an example of a [*right dislocation*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300649/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-shift-an-appositive-away-from-the-noun-it-renames/300652#300652).

Comment: @NigelJ I would have put "It's a good car, that", as fairly standard English - the "that" being there for indicative emphasis. What would definitely be Northern, would be if I said "It's a good car, is the Land Rover" or "He's a fine fellow, is John".

Comment: @WS2 I disagree. Having lived in several parts of the UK I would say, from my own experience, that the usage is localised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are statement tags.  Those two are very informal, and they are used 
with positive statements.

They invite the listener to agree or comment.

{From [English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/tags).}

Comment: Hello, Patriot. Thanks for visiting ELU. Have you a supporting reference to add to improve your answer? Unsupported answers are not considered desirable on ELU; they come across as mere opinion (and sometimes are).

Comment: Hi Edwin!  Thanks for the welcome.  Yes, I can provide support for my answer. If I state an opinion, I will always make that clear.